# Linux: create a directory only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: linux

Is there a simple linux commands to conditionally create a directory?

A sort of `mkdir` that only creates a directory if doesn't exists i.e. doesn't complain if it exists already?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mkdir -p /path/dir

Will make the entire path and will not complain if it already exists.